# UITableViewCell getting the default image when i scroll down and up the UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios5

When i checked a cell, the image associated is changed, but when i had scrolled down and up, the cell got its default image this is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView

         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
    NSArray *listData =[self->tableContents objectForKey:
                        [self->sortedKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]];
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: SimpleTableIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row];
    UIImageView *unchecked = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"]];
UIImageView *checked = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"]];

BOOL bChecked = NO;//By default, it's unchecked, so NO

/// Assign cell according to `bChecked`
cell.accessoryView = (bChecked ? checked : unchecked); 
return cell;

}
```

**EDIT:**

I have edited my code to look as above, but i still get the issue, the default image is getting back when i scroll up my table view.

**EDIT 2:**
@Openside: So according to your approach, my snippet should look like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView

         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
    NSArray *listData =[self->tableContents objectForKey:
                        [self->sortedKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]];

    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: SimpleTableIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    textClass *myText = (textClass*)[listData objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.textLabel.text = myText.text;
    UIImageView *unchecked = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"]];
    UIImageView *checked = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage  imageNamed:@"checked.png"]];



    cell.accessoryView = (myText.isChecked ? checked : unchecked); 
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView

didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    textClass *myText=[[textClass alloc]init];
    myText.isChecked=YES;
}
```

I got this exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x673bc'
```

The line indicating the exception issue is this (in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method):

```
cell.textLabel.text = myText.text;
```

I have added the class textClass although i am not so convinced, i think i can use a property in the holder class of my UITableView.

Comment: The issue is that your listData object isn't being created with a collection (array) of textClass items hence the exception. You you should create a class level variable for listData populate it in loadView with textClass items setting the text to your text value and isChecked = NO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the cell will be refreshed (or reused hence the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier ) when you scroll it out of view and then back into view. You need to have a flag on your source object to say if it's checked or not and then add an if statement to determine if the checked.png or unchecked.png image is used.

However, looking at your code the source object is just text, it may be worth creating a subclassed NSObject with two properties

text and 
checked

Then your cellForRowAtIndexPath code can determine which image to show.

I hope that helps.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView

     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: SimpleTableIdentifier];
if(cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
            reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
}
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
textClass *myText = (textClass*)[listData objectAtIndex:row];
cell.textLabel.text = myText.text;
UIImageView *unchecked = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"]];
UIImageView *checked = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage  imageNamed:@"checked.png"]];



/// Assign cell according to `bChecked`
cell.accessoryView = (myText.isChecked ? checked : unchecked); 
return cell;

}

@interface textClass : NSObject {

@private
    NSString *_text;
    BOOL _isChecked;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *text;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isChecked;

@end

@implementation textClass

@synthesize text = _text;
@synthesize isChecked = _isChecked;

@end
```

Ok so here I have created a class called textClass it has two properties text and isChecked. When you load your view populate an NSMutableArray (listData) with these objects using the text you were previously using. When your cell gets checked set the isChecked property to YES when the cell gets reused this property has retained its state outside of the delegate method and should render correctly.

Comment: @Malek let me know how it goes, don't forget that the interface and implementation need to be in a separate file and listData needs to be an NSMutableArray within your table view controller and probably best to populate it when in loadView.

Comment: Hi Openside, thanx for your approach, actually, i got an exception: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString text]: unrecognized selector`, i will update my post to show you what i did.

Comment: I think the approach of using another class to manage all that is unavoidable, but the problem is that the `cellForRowAtIndexPath ` method gets called every time when the `UITableViewCell` is shown so it seems like i can't declare an instance of my new class inside that method because it will be instantiating each time the cell is shown.

Comment: @Malek if you can post the whole .m file and the .h file somewhere I'll amend it and post it back. The instantation for the new class has to take place outside of cellForRowAtIndexPath so that it can be accessed by that delegate along with didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 2):

As Openside said, while scrolling, the cell will come from dequeue. So, we need to assign image according to new state.

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView    
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = ...; ///< reuse a created cell.
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = ...; ///< create a new cell
    }

    BOOL bChecked = ...///< Decide the cell checked or not.

    /// Assign cell according to `bChecked`
    cell.accessoryView = (bChecked ? imgChecked : imgNonChecked); 
    return cell;

}
```

`Edit:`
As for me, I will decide check status by the method `indexPathForSelectedRow` of tableView. I assume your table view is not multiple selection. It selects only one row at one time.

So, I decide the checked status by following. Because the tableView holds the information about which indexPath is selected.

```
NSIndexPath *selIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
BOOL bChecked = [indexPath isEqual:selIndexPath];
```

Comment: Hi, thanx for your reply, i have adapted your solution but i still have the same problem, please take a look on my EDIT, i have edited the code in my question post.

Comment: @Malek I think you have missed the point a bit, where does bChecked get it's value from in your example? It's only set once and that value is NO. You need to persist the checked state of the object outside of the delegate method so that when the cell comes to be reused the method can set the state. I can elaborate with some code if that will help.

Comment: It would be really of some help if you clarify more your idea in some code because i have tried to put the boolean as a global variable and still don't get what i want, i tried several approaches :(

Comment: @Malek I added some code in my answer above hopefully that will make it a bit clearer. In your edit bChecked has a limited scope where it only exists in cellForRowAtIndexPath and therefore doesn't affect anything.

Comment: @Openside i will check that out and make you know :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the complete code in brackets :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView

         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
    NSArray *listData =[self->tableContents objectForKey:
                        [self->sortedKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]];

    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: SimpleTableIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    textClass *myText = (textClass*)[listData objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.textLabel.text = myText.text;
    UIImageView *unchecked = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"]];
    UIImageView *checked = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage  imageNamed:@"checked.png"]];



    cell.accessoryView = (myText.isChecked ? checked : unchecked); 
}
    return cell;
}
```

This should definitely work.